# Some errors when Using Locator and ServiceLocator in GWT2.4

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Cannot validate this method because the domain mapping for the return   type (XXXProxy) could not be resolved to a domain type Add @SuppressWarnings("requestfactory") to dismiss.

Starting with GWT 2.4, RequestFactory interfaces must be validated before they can be used by the RequestFactory server code or JVM-based clients. This document explains the mechanisms for validating those interfaces.

according to http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation

I have done but came out some error in Proxy and Request class.
like that:

```
Cannot validate this method because the domain mapping for the return   type (XXXProxy) could not be resolved to a domain type Add @SuppressWarnings("requestfactory") to dismiss.
Could not find domain method similar to java.lang.Integer countUsers()。
```

Help！I have passed for using Implementing a service in an entity class
but can't pass Using Locator and ServiceLocator.

Mycode：

```
@ServiceName(value="UserProxy.class", locator="UserServiceLocator.class")
public interface UserServiceRequest extends RequestContext {

    Request<Integer> countUsers();
    Request<Void> generateUsers();
    Request<List<UserProxy>> findAllUsers();
    InstanceRequest<UserProxy, Void> persist();
    InstanceRequest<UserProxy, Void> remove();

}

@ProxyForName(value = "User.class", locator = "UserLocator.class")
public interface UserProxy extends EntityProxy {

    //...setter and getter

    EntityProxyId<UserProxy> stableId();

}
```

error [debug to use method on server]

> com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet doPost
>   严重: Unexpected error
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: The RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run for the com.geogre.shared.DemoRfLocateRequestFactory RequestFactory type
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.impl.Deobfuscator$Builder.load(Deobfuscator.java:59)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ResolverServiceLayer.updateDeobfuscator(ResolverServiceLayer.java:43)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ResolverServiceLayer.resolveRequestFactory(ResolverServiceLayer.java:176)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:172)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:172)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:172)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerCache.getOrCache(ServiceLayerCache.java:233)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerCache.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerCache.java:198)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:207)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:127)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.doPost(RequestFactoryServlet.java:133)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
>       at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
>       at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
>         Pragma: no-cache
>         Cache-Control: no-cache
>      Response headers
>         Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
>         Content-Length: 1420

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using the @ServiceName annotation incorrectly, in a couple of ways. If you want to mention a class literal, use @Service instead

```
@Service(value=MyServiceType.class, locator=MyServiceLocator.class)
```

If you want to use @ServiceName, you need the full package name

```
@ServiceName(value="com.company.server.MyServiceType", locator="com.company.gwt.MyServiceLocator")
```

The same is true for @ProxyFor and @ProxyForName, which you also seem to be using incorrectly.

In any case, you can't make the RequestContext's service point to a proxy - it should probably point to User, not UserProxy.

Comment: if I use @Service instead，come out with “Could not find domain method similar to " edit error after rebuilt

Comment: and error "The RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run for the XXX RequestFactory type"

Comment: Make sure you are running the annotation processor tool - and make sure that your domain type actually has the method in question, for example if @Service(User) UserSericeRequest has a persist() method, then User must have one - and you shouldn't be using a ServiceLocator. Can you update your post to have proxies and requests with annotations that make sense, the service and entities that they refer to, and the full error message you get with that setup - it'll make it easier to offer suggestions.

Comment: thx and I post the error just now, about your idea"make sure that your domain type actually has the method in question, for example if @Service(User) UserSericeRequest has a persist() method, then User must have one ",e...I want to us Locator and ServiceLocator,I don't want to implement persistence code in an entity itself.